# Method for organizing and storing user information

Tags: swift

I am working on an app where the user can create a list of Clients, and a list of daily schedules that contain an ordered array of Clients.

I am trying to figure out the best way to organize this information to be stored.

Currently, I am storing the array of clients, and representing them in the daily schedules by a unique ID. This rational for this is that it allows for only updating one place if a clients information changes. However, this would still require filtering through everything to delete their ID out of each daily schedule if the user wished to delete a client.

Something like:

```
struct Client {
  let clientID: Int
  let name: String
  let mowFrequency: Int
}

struct OneDay {
  let creationDate: Date
  let schedule: [Int]
}

struct ExampleView: View {
  @State var clients: [Client] = [
    Client(clientID: 23, name: “Jon”, mowFrequency: 7),
    Client(clientID: 3, name: “Andrew”, mowFrequency: 7),
    Client(clientID: 7, name: “Andrea”, mowFrequency: 6)
  ]
  @State var days: [OneDay] = [
    OneDay(creationDate: Date(), schedule: [7, 23])
  ]


  var body: some View {
    //code for view
  }
}
```

I’m not really asking for code, but I thought I’d provide an example. If anyone has any better ideas for how to represent the information, I’d love to hear them. Thanks!

Comment: I think you're looking for a Database. Be CoreData, SwiftData (which is based on CoreData), Realm, Firebase, or any other database solution.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I am more going for a general method for how to group the user data in a way that is efficient and fits the problem supplied in the post. My code was simply how I’m considering solving it, not the actual problem.